# Checkbox selected by default in popup

Tags: javascript

I have a checkbox that when selected it opens a div (#block) revealing different options.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cbxShowHide"/>
<label class="styled-input" for="cbxShowHide">My Label</label>


<div id="block" class="closed-block">
Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script>
jQuery('#cbxShowHide').change(function(){
        if (this.checked) {
            jQuery('#block').slideDown(200).trigger('show');
            jQuery('#block').addClass('open');
        }
        else {
            jQuery('#block').slideUp(200).trigger('hide');
            jQuery('#block').removeClass('open');
        }                   
    });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
#block {display:none;}
```

In other words, the DIV (#block) is hidden by default, and it opens when selecting the checkbox.

This works great on a page... However the same is used on a different page, but in a popup. However in this popup I wanted to have the checkbox selected and the DIV open by default.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the attribute `checked`.

With HTML : `<input type="checkbox" id="cbxShowHide" checked="checked" />`

With jQuery : `jQuery("#cbxShowHide").prop("checked", true);`

Comment: Hi - This is actually in Wordpress. The same file is used by the page and by the popup. So I could not add the checked attribute.  I believe it needs to be done with JavaScript.

Comment: ok, you can use jQuery('#cbxShowHide').prop("checked", true);

Comment: And how do I apply that to the popup only?

Comment: Maybe you have to learn more about jQuery.
Your popup has to be uniquely identifiable, e.g. with an id="popup" on the root element of the popup. Then you can use jQuery('#popup #cbxShowHide').prop("checked", true);

Note that an id should always be unique in a page. So it's not a good pratice to have 2 id="cbxShowHide" in the same page.